# The relation between piano 12-scale and Fibonacci?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

One of my books says there is a relation between the chromatic musical scale [CC#DD#EFF#GG#AA#BC] and the Fibonacci sequence. So...what's the relation?

Comment: I think it is good to mention the name of the book, instead of just saying *one of my books*. IMO it is a part of useful background for a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain there is a "real" relation, but there does seem to be a coincidental relationship, particularly if you look at a piano keyboard.

There are 13 chromatic notes from C to C.  Of these 5 are black keys (C#, D#, F#, G# A#) and 8 are white keys.  Further, the black keys are grouped 2 and 3, because there are 2 white keys (E, F) between (C#, D#) and (F#, G# A#), but only 1 white key between black keys generally.

So you have a manifestation of the numbers 2, 3, 5, 8, and 13, which does bear a superficial relationship to the Fibonacci sequence.  I don't see how you extend this, and as I noted, this  might just be an interesting coincidence.

Comment: yes, maybe this is the answer, I didn't notice that.